# Why does my website shrink for mobile?

Tags: mobile, mobile-website

The main div is 600 pixels wide. By my understanding, an iPhone 5 is 640 pixels wide. But when I pull the website up on the iPhone 5, the main div only takes up a small fraction of the screen, maybe a third. Why is that?

[Website](http://qpo.io)

Comment: Are you using css tranform? Like rotating an image.

Comment: Probably. It's built with the Raphael library, which provides a Javascript interface to manipulate DOM elements more powerfully than jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've seen IOS shrink content so that the whole page is displayed on the phone screen when using css transforms.

So the offending css was

```
            background: url('/images/mobile-device-down-arrow.gif') no-repeat center; 
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1);
```

we replaced it with

```
            background: url('/images/mobile-device-up-arrow.gif') no-repeat center;
```

and it fixed the problem.

I remember a bug in webkit for this, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: So basically, if I use transforms, I am doomed?

Comment: That's what we found.   Once we replaced the transform code, we no longer had the issue of our site shrinking.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me and I managed to fix the issue by wrapping the affected elements that were being shrunk in a div that defined the exact width that the element needed to be, in my case this was: `width: calc(100vw - 2rem);`

Hopefully this helps anybody having this issue, it seems to only occur on mobile devices when using the rotate transform with transition at any positive degree as when removing the transform, the element reverted to 0deg without shrinking.